# Manipulating retrieved data that is being echoed by an external PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't consider myself a professional by any means.  I decided to spend this summer picking up a few web languages that would allow me to prototype my ideas (I am a designer).

To get with the question, I am having a tough time figuring out how to manipulate elements that I am echoing back from an external .php script.  Essentially I am doing this.

process_feed.php:
- Gets data, does SQL search based on data, outputs rows

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($feedResult))
    {
       $ctime = date("U",strtotime($row['timestamp']));

       echo '<div id="secretmsg">'.$row['secretmsg'].'</br>';
       echo '<div id="postedby">Posted By: '.$row['postedby'].'</div>';
       echo '<div id="timestamp">'.ago($ctime).'</div><button type ="button" name="'.$row['m_id'].'">Reply</button></div>';
    }
```

main page:

```
 function RefreshFeed()
{    

    var SchoolName = document.getElementById('schoolname').innerHTML;

    $.post('../../process_feed.php', {name: SchoolName}, processResponse);

    function processResponse(data) {
    $('.secretfeed').html(data);

    }



}
```

Perhaps not the best solution, but I have RefreshFeed on an interval so I can constantly get updated information.

The issue is this:  I am trying to work on a comment system where users can respond to each post.  On my process page, I am adding a Reply button with the name set to the ID in the database.  I am trying to setup basic functionality where the Reply button will open up a text input for commenting, send the message to the DB based on the ID, etc etc.  However, on my main page I am not able to manipulate the element because it's being echoed?  What can I change in order to echo information from the database onto my main page, and then from my main page manipulate the echoed div's.

I hope this makes sense - thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you try `$.post('../../process_feed.php', {name: SchoolName}, processResponse(data));` ?

Comment: Doing that made the page not show the information from the external PHP script.  It seems I have to code the functionality of the comment system on the external PHP script since the Reply button is being echoed there?

Comment: By 'functionality', do you mean the Javascript?

Comment: Both I suppose.  The javascript for inputting the comment, and then the ajax/PHP to send it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you would like to modify the DOM once the data has been added - so you can then just use a selector to get the desired element and do what ever you want - e.g.:

```
function processResponse(data) {

    // Selector to get all elements by class name within the whole document
    $('.secretfeed').html(data);

    // Selector to get all buttons by tag name inside $('.secretfeed')
    $('.secretfeed').find('button').text('foo'); 

    // Selector to get all buttons by attribute inside $('.secretfeed')
    $('.secretfeed').find('[type="button"]').text('bar');

    // Selector to get the element with the given id within the whole document
    $('#secretmsg').css('color', '#ff0000');

}
```

**Notes:**

**Ids for HTML elements should always be unique within the whole document!** In your example you possibly echo multiple elements with the same id (as it is inside a while loop) - use `class=""` instead.

It is recommended to save selectors so that jQuery does not need to parse the DOM over and over again - e.g.:

```
var $myselector = $('.myclass');
$myselector.text('foo');
```

But keep in mind that the selector is not updated when you modify the DOM by e.g. adding another element with `class="myclass"` - you would then need to assign the variable again so the selector contains the newly inserted element as well.

Additionally be sure that the DOM is ready when you want to work on it - regarding your callback `processResponse` this will always be the case as jQuery takes care of it and does not execute the callback until it is ready - but when you come from a page reload wrap your code like this:

```
var $myselector = $();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $myselector = $('.myclass');
});
```

**Additional info:**

Finally (out of the scope of your question) take a look at event delegation so that you do not need to select all elements directly - e.g. if you want to add a click handler to all of your buttons you do not need to register an event handler for each but can create a global one:

```
$(document).on('click', '.secretfeed button', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: Do you have a place where I can talk to you about this one on one?  Im not sure if this website has private message - I couldn't find it.